# How to expel a rect from inside another rect - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, collision, rect

I am trying to make `rect1` move out from inside `rect2`. I have tried to look around for an awsner but i am unable to find a satisfactory awnser. I can detect the rectangles intersecting, but i cannot expel `rect1` so it goes outside `rect2`. Can you provide some code to help me do this? I will provide my detection code so far.

Code:

```
var DoCollision = function(rect1, rect2, objectToMove){
    if (rect1.x + rect1.w > rect2.x &&
        rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.w &&
        rect1.y + rect1.h > rect2.y &&
        rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.h){
            // Expel rect1 from rect2 here using objectToMove as the object being expelled (In this case, rect1).
    };
};
```

Thank you for responding if you do.

i should tell you the bigger picture. I am trying to make a function where i input 3 `rect` objects, to test if they are colliding or not, and if so, i want the third `rect` object to move accordingly. For example, the function parameters are `rect1`, `rect2`, `rect1`, meaning when `rect1` intersects `rect2` on the left side, i want the third parameter `rect1` to move left

Comment: What do you mean by "expel"? Also, what is "objectToMove"?

Comment: Could you provide more context for this question? Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you're not really taking a correct approach (the function makes no sense of its own)

Comment: I can paste my whole code in if that would be nice?

Comment: by expel, i mean, to move rect1 outside rect2.

Comment: @JammehCarr that is probably too much. Try to isolate the problem and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: mvce?  what do you mean by that?

Comment: @JammehCarr see edited comment

Comment: Why is that? I think i should tell you the bigger picture. I am trying to make a function where i input 3 `rect` objects, to test if they are colliding or not, and if so, i want the third `rect` object to move accordingly. For example, the function parameters are `rect1, rect2, rect1`, meaning when `rect1` intersects `rect2` on the left side, i want the third parameter `rect1` to move left

Comment: Is it safe to assume objectToMove will always be equal to either rect1 or rect2?

Comment: Yes, you can safely assume that

Comment: @JammehCarr Please add your clarifying comments as edits to the question. Do not say "look at the comments" in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to identify the minimum amount needed to move in either X or Y directions and then move that amount. This does not take any bounding rectangles into account:

```
function doCollision(rect1, rect2, objectToMove){
    if (rect1.x + rect1.w > rect2.x &&
        rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.w &&
        rect1.y + rect1.h > rect2.y &&
        rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.h){
            if (objectToMove === rect1) {
                moveOutside(objectToMove, rect2);
            }
            else if (objectToMove === rect2) {
                moveOutside(objectToMove, rect1);
            }
    };
};

function moveOutside(rectToMove, otherRect) {
    // Determine if the overlap is due more to x or to y,
    // then perform the appropriate move

    var moveOverOtherX = rectToMove.x + rectToMove.w - otherRect.x;
    var otherOverMoveX = otherRect.x + otherRect.w - rectToMove.x;

    var moveOverOtherY = rectToMove.y + rectToMove.h - otherRect.y;
    var otherOverMoveY = otherRect.y + otherRect.h - rectToMove.y;

    var minOver = Math.min(moveOverOtherX, otherOverMoveX, moveOverOtherY, otherOverMoveY);

    if (minOver == moveOverOtherX) {
        rectToMove.x = otherRect.x - rectToMove.w;
    }
    else if (minOver == otherOverMoveX) {
        rectToMove.x = otherRect.x + otherRect.w;
    }
    else if (minOver == moveOverOtherY) {
        rectToMove.y = otherRect.y - rectToMove.h;
    }
    else {
        rectToMove.y = otherRect.y + otherRect.h;
    }

    rectToMove.update();
}
```

See it in [a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/rbpc6c29/1/).

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for awnsering late, but this is greatly appreciated and i hope i didnt waste you're time though :3 :) thank you

Comment: No problem. I love graphics and simulation, so this was useful to reason about. Of course, it would be better to render the objects on a canvas (ideally with webgl) rather than in the DOM, but the simulation part should work with any view layer (with the exception that the Y-axis is reversed in GL).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
var DoCollision = function(rect1, rect2, objectToMove){
    if (rect1.x + rect1.w > rect2.x &&
        rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.w &&
        rect1.y + rect1.h > rect2.y &&
        rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.h){
            objectToMove.x = Math.max(rect1.x + rect1.w, rect2.x + rect2.w);
            objectToMove.y = Math.max(rect1.y + rect1.h, rect2.y + rect2.h);
    };
};
```

But note that this will only work if there are only two rectangles in your entire dataset.  If there are many rectangles, moving rect1 to avoid a collision with rect2 may create a collision with some other rectangle(s).  In general the problem of moving objects the minimal distance to avoid collisions with all other objects is very hard (probably NP-hard, though I haven't verified this).

**EDIT**: Moving a colliding object back away from the collision is probably best done by checking whether the collision will happen BEFORE you change the position of the moving object (i.e., compute the desired position, check if it will cause a collision, and if so don't move the object at all).  But if you must do it afterwards, you can generalize the above approach:

```
var DoCollision = function(rect1, rect2, objectToMove){
    var intersectInX = rect1.x + rect1.w > rect2.x &&
                       rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.w;
    var intersectInY = rect1.y + rect1.h > rect2.y &&
                       rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.h;
    var collide = intersectInX && intersectInY;
    if ( ! collide ) { return; }
    if (intersectInX) {
        var leftmostEdge = Math.min(rect1.x, rect2.x);
        var rightmostEdge = Math.max(rect1.x, rect2.x);
        if (objectToMove.x > leftmostEdge) { // move right rectangle
            objectToMove.x = rightmostEdge;
        } else {                             // move left rectangle
            objectToMove.x = leftmostEdge - objectToMove.w;
        }
    }
    if (intersectInY) {
        var topmostEdge = Math.min(rect1.y, rect2.y);
        var bottommostEdge = Math.max(rect1.y, rect2.y);
        if (objectToMove.y > topmostEdge) { // move bottom rectangle
            objectToMove.y = bottommostEdge;
        } else {                            // move top rectangle
            objectToMove.y = topmostEdge - objectToMove.h;
        }
    }
};
```

This doesn't address 2 cases in which you need to decide how you want the rectangles to behave:
1) If one rectangle completely encloses the other.  They will be moved apart, but not necessarily in the way that you want.
2) If the movement causes intersection with the outer border.